# Getting user id from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userid

I wonder is it still possible to get Facebook user ID if I got 'only' the user's profile (profile username/link)?

For instance:

```
https://www.facebook.com/zuck
```

I've tried to do this with SDK and Graph API but it seems that all previous solutions don't work. Could you please give me a hint? I would like to go further but I'm not sure which way is correct.

Comment: No it is not possible without scraping which is not allowed by Facebook Terms of Service or Facebook Platform Policy

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Excel. I put the macros that I use. You have to put the name in the first column and it will generate the id in the second column when you run the GenerateFaceIds macro. (You need to be logged into Facebook in IExplorer)

```
Sub GenerateFaceIds()
  Dim total As Long
  total = 1

   Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(total, 1)) = True
   If (Cells(total, 2) = "") Then
       Call faceId(total)
    End If
    total = total + 1
   Loop

    MsgBox ("OK")
End Sub

Sub faceId(row As Long)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    Dim id As String
    id = Cells(row, 1)

    With appIE
        .Navigate "https://www.facebook.com/" + id
        .Visible = False
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Text = appIE.Document.Body.innerHTML

    posinter = InStr(Text, "profile_owner")
    profile_owner = Mid(Text, posinter + 16, 15)

    posinter2 = InStr(profile_owner, """")
    If posinter2 > 0 Then
        profile_owner = Left(profile_owner, posinter2 - 1)
    End If

    Cells(row, 2) = profile_owner

    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing

ExitSub:

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    'MsgBox "Something's wrong"

    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing

    Resume ExitSub
    Resume

End Sub
```

Result:

zuck    4